# How can I break a while loop with the press of a key?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I want to write code using a `while` loop, but I want to break the loop when I press a key, and if I did not press a key then the loop continues. For example, in this code, I want the program to print natural numbers until I press a key.

How can I do that?

```
int main()
{
    int i= 1;
    while(true)
    {   
       cout<<i<<" ";
       i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using visual studio, include conio.h, then use something like `if (_kbhit()) { _getche(); return 0; }`

Comment: @Kitswas it doesn't, because that code pauses the loop while waiting for keyboard input. The OP doesn't want to pause the loop.

Comment: @AndersK thank you , that code works but can you tell me how ? what is kbhit ?

Comment: @Kitswas no because I dont want program wait for input.

Comment: You can press Ctrl-C to interrupt a program. Then you do not have to change the code at all.

Comment: @j6t it was just example I was looking for a code to break the loop .

Comment: The _kbhit checks the keyboard buffer after a character, the getche reads the character. So when the user presses a key, the character is entered into the keyboard buffer